# Are user form inputs vulnerable if page innerHTML is restored to state prior to inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, security

I have a page containing a form that gathers user inputs to populate a table then this table can then be printed with the user inputs. Using javascript I am restoring the documents innerHTML to the state prior to user form inputs after the table is printed. My question is are these user inputs still stored in browser cache or otherwise vulnerable. This page is not coded with session storage or cookies.

```
<script>
    function printContent(el){
        var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
        var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where/how/if browser saves an HTML fragment is absolutely unknown/unpredictable/browser+version dependent. You're printing the document then data is available all through the system. You can't help with this. What you can do is to, at least,  disable `autocomplete`.

Comment: I do have autocomplete set to "off" in the form. So, what is best practice to avoid vulnerability?

Comment: There isn't, honestly and AFAIK, much you can do. We may assume that deleted HTML fragment isn't cached but it's an assumption and for sure memory isn't cleared (just released). Also going through the printer will create temporary files and send that data to few drivers, filters and other printer related system software (and each one can leak). Data will be then sent through the wire (if not wireless) and maybe even cached in the printer itself. It's not easy even using lower level languages, from an HTML app...

Comment: Assuming the user is on personal device, not public device, what is your risk assessment 1 being low, 10 being high?

Comment: Just **an uninformed guess** but assuming device is secured (system is not compromised, in that case there is almost nothing you can do) then I'd say 2/3 (mostly because if system isn't trusted then nothing is secure). It's not 1 only because with a _native_ application you have some more control over memory (which might be zeroed before being freed)

Comment: Adriano. Will you post your comment as answer so that I may upvote.

Comment: I think it's really too _poor_ to be an answer and with way too many assumptions and guesses.  Just wait if someone will come up with a better one!